# How to get received sms from sms web service without page refresh and auto

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have a web service for send sms from website. I can get the received sms by calling Page_load codes. But I want get this messages automatically then send a message(sms) to sender. It means I want relpay to his sms without page load or refresh page automatically.

Comment: No Has not been used from AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your data into a div, Use ajax and call your ajaxified function after every desired time using interval. ...

some thing like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var refresh = setInterval(function(){
  // Do something every 1 seconds like call an ajax function
    $('#youdiv').ajax(); //this is dummy, for right syntax follow the link at the end of answer
}, 1000);  // 1000 equals to 1 sec
```

});

Read more about ajax

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I want reply to sender without my site page is open. Is .ashx could be an option to my question?

Comment: yes jquery ajax support all type of server side language, all the game is hidden in server side file, jquery ajax will help you to call your server side page and fetch the results without refreshing the page and setInterval will help to call ajax again and again, so your div will refreshed after every x time.


I will suggest you to read jquery ajax at jquery website, google will definitely help you.

Comment: Do not need to be page opens? Site was not always open.

Comment: jquery ajax automatically opens the page ... just you need to print the results in the page which will be accessed by ajax

Comment: Suppose I don't want our computer is turned on. Then what will do for this issue?